# Create a Link to Resource Monitor

Tags: windows-7, windows, shortcuts, performance-monitor

I'm running windows 7 and **I want to create a link to the resource monitor that I can place anywhere**. But all I've been able to do was pin it to the taskbar and not the start menu. Is there a command to run the RM so that I can paste it inside a shortcut?

The reason is that I have a costumized toolbar on my taskbar that groups the most useful/common control panel applications (such as system restore and windows update) and I'd like the resource monitor to be in there. Any ideas?

Thanks

EDIT:Changed to say Resource monitor, instead of Performance Monitor.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create a shortcut with this as target:

```
%windir%\system32\perfmon.exe /res
```

Comment: +1 I just tried this and it works form me - thanks!

Comment: My bad, I ment resource monitor instead of performance monitor. Just edited my question to fix that. Still know of a way?  =)
(+1 for the correct answer anyway)

Comment: Changed accordingly!

Comment: Thanks, it works great! Actually, I tested it like then times, and it always ran performance monitor anyway. When I was about to comment on my failure, I tested it again and it worked perfectly. =P
Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Although it's off topic this is fun, or frightening depending on your point of view.

perfmon -report

perfmon /report  (if you prefer)

Comment: cool , didnt know that one